# Examples of advancement in mathematics due to war

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list

It's not a lie that, in most sciences, some of their advancement comes from war. A couple examples would be the [Haber process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process) in chemistry and none other than the [Manhattan Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project) in both physics and chemistry, both coming from the infamous World War 2.

My question is: **has there ever been advancement in mathematics due to war?**

Comment: There are stories about theorems being proved in war prison camps.

Comment: You're using "extrapolate" wrong. :-)

Comment: Yes I am, sorry. Would you kindly extend your answer?

Comment: Nah, sorry. I'm too busy to rummage through the internet and find the story. I do recall someone, perhaps the same person I have in mind, teaching topology in a similar scenario (to avoid having his real expertise found out and exploited by his captors). Probably searching on Google something like "war prisoner camp math" will do the trick.

Comment: There's a german book called _mathemathik in kreige_ (_mathematics in war_), can't seem to find it though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are thinking of Jean Leray.

Comment: I might be bistaken, but I think differential equations were developed in order to calculate preciselly trajectories for ballistic purposes. I don't remember the war itself though...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, I think I was thinking about Jean Leray. (Although I think there was another example of prison camp math in the form of graph theory or something, to which I referred in the first comment.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I believe you mean [Paul Turán](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Turan.html).

Comment: @Miguelgondu [This guy](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Riebesell) released such a book in 1916.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operations research was explored during WW2. See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research#Second_World_War

Answer (score 3):

There is a very entertaining book by T.W. Korner called *The Pleasures of Counting* in which he discusses among other things how the Allies nearly lost WW2. It's been a while since I read the book but the naval effort was rescued by mathematicians in an ingenious and essentially simple way.

Cryptography is another field in which WWII may have spurred advancement but I can't say for sure whether it involved novel math or just increased attention and ingenuity.

Answer (score 3):

"Decision mathematics" was spurred by the first war regarding resource allocation, linear programming for example. My A-level teacher introduced us with this topic.

Cryptography also progressed in leaps and bounds as well as computing because of the need for cryptography.

The Curta mechanical calculator was invented by a Jew (Curta) in a concentration camp.

Answer (score 2):

Game theory's development accelerated at a record pace during World War II/Cold War.
If one nation changed the balance of power (by building a missile-defense shield, for instance), would it lead to a strategic blunder that resulted in nuclear war? Governments consulted game theorists to prevent such imbalances.

Comment: Do you mean the Cold War?

Answer (score 1):

Asaf was referring to André Weil, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Weil

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to Weil. I was talking about Jean Leray.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My apologies. But Weil also belongs to the math-in-prison category.